# Replace "( with name Tr in powershell text file

Tags: windows, powershell

How do we replace these two special characters considered as one ->  `"(` to `Tr`.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\marich\Desktop\richi\*.sql" -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {
    (Get-Content $_) -Replace '''"(''', 'Tr'| Set-Content $_
}
```

kindly need assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `-replace` you would need to escape the `(` with `\` to match it literally as it is a regex special character. See [**Escaping characters**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.3#escaping-characters).

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\marich\Desktop\richi\*.sql" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_ -Raw) -replace '"\(', 'Tr' | Set-Content $_
}
```

It's much easier with [`.Replace`, the String method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0), where everything is matched literally and no escaping is needed:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\marich\Desktop\richi\*.sql" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_ -Raw).Replace('"(', 'Tr') | Set-Content $_
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for the explanation ..worked both the  ways!!

Comment: @malcolmrichard glad it was helpful